# Devise - "Scoping" per-user system tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am making a simple application where the user can delete, edit, view and create tasks, the tasks have description, title and date that should be executed.

I deployed the devise to register users and user login, but I have difficulty "scoping" the tasks by user, that is, the user will log in and can view, edit and delete only the tasks created by him.

My schema:

```
  ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170407164641) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "tarefas", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "titulo"
    t.text     "descricao"
    t.datetime "data"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_tarefas_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
  end

end
```

I used belongs_to: user and has_many: tasks.

My tasks_controller:

```
    class TarefasController < ApplicationController

before_filter :authenticate_user!

def index
    @tarefa = Tarefa.all
end

def show
    @tarefa = Tarefa.find(params[:id])

 end

def new
    @tarefa = Tarefa.new
end

def edit
    @tarefa = Tarefa.find(params[:id])
end

def create
     @tarefa = Tarefa.new(tarefa_params)
     @user = current_user
     if @tarefa.save
        redirect_to @tarefa
     else
        render 'new'
     end
end

def update
    @tarefa = Tarefa.find(params[:id])
    if @tarefa.update(tarefa_params)
        redirect_to @tarefa
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @tarefa = Tarefa.find(params[:id])
    @tarefa.destroy

    redirect_to tarefas_path
end

private
  def tarefa_params
    params.require(:tarefa).permit(:titulo, :descricao, :data)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You have created one to many relationship between User and Tarefa models, create a new Tarefa record under user

I suppose these task editing/ modifying options are available to user after login only so Change your controller as:

```
def edit
    @tarefa = current_user.tarefas.find_by(id: params[:id])
end

def create
     @tarefa = current_user.tarefas.new(tarefa_params)
     @user = current_user
     if @tarefa.save
        redirect_to @tarefa
     else
        render 'new'
     end
end

def update
    @tarefa = current_user.tarefas.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if @tarefa.update(tarefa_params)
        redirect_to @tarefa
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @tarefa = current_user.tarefas.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @tarefa.destroy

    redirect_to tarefas_path
end

private
  def tarefa_params
    params.require(:tarefa).permit(:titulo, :descricao, :data)
  end
end
```

When you want to list all tarefas related to user, you can use

```
list_of_user_tasks = current_user.tarefas
```

or

```
 user = User.find_by(id: any_user_id)
 list_of_user_tasks = user.tarefas
```

This is basic and simple, there are more methods though.